# Dagger 2 Custom Scope for each Activity

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Do I need to create each scope for every single activity? Can't I define only a default scope for every activity for fragment?

Comment: it depends on your needs. Your instance is shared between activities or every activity must has its own instance of your object

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have an `@ActivityScope` or `@ActivityScoped` object applied to multiple sibling activity components, and it will work the way you expect: As long as you create exactly one new subcomponent per activity instance, then each will have access to `@ActivityScope` bindings that will live in their respective components.

```
@ApplicationScope @Component(/* ... */)
interface ApplicationComponent {
  FooActivitySubcomponent createFoo();
  BarActivitySubcomponent createBar();
  // ...
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(/* ... */)
interface FooActivitySubcomponent {
  void inject(FooActivity activity);
  // ...
}

@ActivityScope @Subcomponent(/* ... */)
interface BarActivitySubcomponent {
  void inject(BarActivity activity);
  // ...
}
```

Of course, [Module.subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Module.html#subcomponents--) is a better way to specify subcomponents in production, and of course [dagger.android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) is an automatic way to create a structure like this.